# ADB Android log to SD card or another location on the device

Tags: android, logging, adb

So i am trying to trouble shoot an issue with an andriod app, however when the issue happens we are not at a pc.  When we get to a pc, the logs are already over written.  My question is if there is any way to run ADB from the device itself and have it log to an SD card or another location on the device.

This way all logs will be captured when the issue occurs.  Perhaps there is a way to access the android terminal on the device and enable to the logging form there?

Thanks

Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is you can use `adb shell` and in the shell type `logcat>/sdcard/log.txt` another way is you can do it via a terminal emulator app from play store, or you can do it programically in an app by executing it with the exec command  just use `"logcat>/sdcard/log.txt"` you can find more documentation about logcat [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html)

Comment: You would need something like setsid for that to keep running when you disconnect the usb cable  killing the shell and any process remaining its child.

Comment: hey Chris, Can you me with that having it running as a child process while it's not connected to the pc?  I need something that will log it to a file.  So say hours later after the issue occured, we can view the logs and see say from 9-5 activities

Answer (score 0):

SysLog at https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.tortel.syslog/ will do this for you. You need a PC with an adb shell to give it permission to read the logs, but after that it can run autonomously on the Android device.

Fdroid has other log readers: search for "logcat".

Answer (score -1):

To capture log in the background is to trivial, another option is to read the log at real time even you do not have a pc at hand.

You can try this great application "[Logcat Window](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.renjing.logscreenfree)" to display logcat on a floating window of your device.

And to use it on a device with Android 4.1 and higher, you need to follow the instructions on the application description page to grant the read log permission with ADB shell before the first usage.

Comment: So this will log continually for hours and Ill get all the logs when they are mailed?  The problem we were having is that the buffer size for the logs were just over writing the log when the issue occurred.

Comment: So that tool won't work, it still just printing the buffer and not a complete set of the logs, say from 9-5.